# Is layered broadcasting available in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I wonder if there is a built-in operation which would free my code from Python-loops.

The problem is this: I have two matrices `A` and `B`. `A` has `N` rows and `B` has `N` columns. I would like to multiply every `i` row from `A` with corresponding `i` column from `B` (using NumPy broadcasting). The resulting matrix would form `i` layer in the output. So my result would be 3-dimensional array.

Is such operation available in NumPy?

Comment: I like this explanation because of the graphics - http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in it's simplest form you just add "zero" dimensions so the NumPy broadcasts along the rows of `A` and columns of `B`:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> A = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4) # 3 row, 4 colums
>>> B = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3) # 5 rows, 3 columns
>>> res = A[None, ...] * B[..., None]
>>> res
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  4,   5,   6,   7],
        [ 16,  18,  20,  22]],

       [[  0,   3,   6,   9],
        [ 16,  20,  24,  28],
        [ 40,  45,  50,  55]],

       [[  0,   6,  12,  18],
        [ 28,  35,  42,  49],
        [ 64,  72,  80,  88]],

       [[  0,   9,  18,  27],
        [ 40,  50,  60,  70],
        [ 88,  99, 110, 121]],

       [[  0,  12,  24,  36],
        [ 52,  65,  78,  91],
        [112, 126, 140, 154]]])
```

The result has a shape of `(5, 3, 4)` and you can easily move the axis around if you want a different shape. For example using [`np.moveaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

```
>>> np.moveaxis(res, (0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 1))  # 0 -> 2 ; 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   3,   6,   9,  12],
        [  0,   6,  12,  18,  24],
        [  0,   9,  18,  27,  36]],

       [[  4,  16,  28,  40,  52],
        [  5,  20,  35,  50,  65],
        [  6,  24,  42,  60,  78],
        [  7,  28,  49,  70,  91]],

       [[ 16,  40,  64,  88, 112],
        [ 18,  45,  72,  99, 126],
        [ 20,  50,  80, 110, 140],
        [ 22,  55,  88, 121, 154]]])
```

With a shape of `(3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it some more, because first check is top, bottom corner of the resulting array, it should be `36` (and it is not :-D). And the depth should be 3.

Comment: @greenoldman Then it's `np.moveaxis(res, (0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 1))`. From the question it wasn't exactly clear what result shape you desired so I made a guess (which was wrong). :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to express your requirement directly is by using [`np.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy.einsum):

```
>>> A = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
>>> B = np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3)
>>> np.einsum('...i,j...->...ij', A, B)
array([[[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   3,   6,   9,  12],
        [  0,   6,  12,  18,  24],
        [  0,   9,  18,  27,  36]],

       [[  4,  16,  28,  40,  52],
        [  5,  20,  35,  50,  65],
        [  6,  24,  42,  60,  78],
        [  7,  28,  49,  70,  91]],

       [[ 16,  40,  64,  88, 112],
        [ 18,  45,  72,  99, 126],
        [ 20,  50,  80, 110, 140],
        [ 22,  55,  88, 121, 154]]])
```

This uses the [Einstein summation convention](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html).

For further discussion, see chapter 3 of [Vectors, Pure and Applied: A General Introduction to Linear Algebra](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RO_TMc7ETPEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by T. W. Körner. In it, the author cites an amusing passage from Einstein's letter to a friend:

> "I have made a great discovery in mathematics; I have suppressed the summation sign every time that the summation must be made over an index which occurs twice..."

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted you of course, but it is hard to choose which answer to accept, both are good, I hope you don't mind I do it by time :-).